# How to put radio button input into parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making a sign up screen for my android application. I already know how to set usernames, passwords and stuff like that. Now I have a radio group with two radio buttons inside to select a gender. How can I set a listener to know which radio button was selected and then upload selected gender to parse.com? This is what I have so far:

```
    protected EditText mUsername;
    protected EditText mPassword;
    protected EditText mEmail;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected RadioButton mFemaleButton;
    protected RadioButton mMaleButton;
    protected Button mSignUpButton;
    protected Button mCancelButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_lastname);
        mFemaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleButton);
        mMaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleButton);
        mCancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

            }
        });

        mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String name = mName.getText().toString();

                username = username.trim();
                password = password.trim();
                email = email.trim();
                name = name.trim();

                if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()
                        || name.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            SignUpActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                            .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    final ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                    newUser.setUsername(username);
                    newUser.setPassword(password);
                    newUser.setEmail(email);
                    newUser.put("name", mName.getText().toString());

                    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                TextlyApplication
                                        .updateParseInstallation(ParseUser
                                                .getCurrentUser());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,
                                        MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        SignUpActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                                null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
maleRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
             newUser.put(COLUMN_GENDER, MALE);
             newUser.saveInBackground(); // if you want to save immediately
        }
    }
});

femaleRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
             newUser.put(COLUMN_GENDER, FEMALE);
             newUser.saveInBackground(); // if you want to save immediately
        }
    }
});
```

**Edited answer:**

1. Add this code:

   ```
   private static final String COLUMN_GENDER = ""; //put here name of your column from table on Parse.com
   private static final String MALE = ""; //put here value for male. Check the type of gender column on Parse.com (String, Number (Integer), Boolean, etc.)
   private static final String FEMALE = ""; //put here value for female. Check the type of gender column on Parse.com (String, Number (Integer), Boolean, etc.)
   ```

   below this your line `protected Button mCancelButton;`
2. Add this code:

   ```
   String gender = mMaleButton.isChecked() ? MALE : FEMALE;
   ```

   below these your lines:

   ```
   username = username.trim();
   password = password.trim();
   email = email.trim();
   name = name.trim();
   ```
3. Add this code:

   ```
   newUser.put(COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
   ```

   below these your lines:

   ```
   final ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
   newUser.setUsername(username);
   newUser.setPassword(password);
   newUser.setEmail(email);
   newUser.put("name", mName.getText().toString());
   ```

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work? I edited my question and added my full code from that activity. Also, I have my radio buttons inside of a radio group. I'm still kind of new to android so I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.